# List of Child Layouts in C# Razor Page

Tags: c#, razor

Is it possible to get list of razor templates called when in a razor layout?

I'm trying to add classing to  elements using template names but, without inserting much code in files.  Is finding a child/ parent list or hierarchy possible while in some razor page?

```
@model MySite.Oranges
@{
    ViewBag.Title = @Model.PageTitle;
    Layout = "~/Views/_Oranges.cshtml";
}

@model MySite.Apples
@{
    ViewBag.Title = @Model.PageTitle;
    Layout = "~/Views/_Apples.cshtml";
}

@model MySite.Grapes
@{
    ViewBag.Title = @Model.PageTitle;
    Layout = "~/Views/_Grapes.cshtml";
}
```

Can _Grapes.cshtml show `<body class="Grapes Apples Oranges">`?